# How to check if an object with specific key-value exists

Tags: javascript

i have a response from the API something like this:

```
var res = [{data: "street_number", label: "121"},
           {data: "route", label: "Ladbroke Grove"},
           {data: "postal_town", label: "London"},
           {data: "administrative_area_level_1", label: "England"},
           {data: "postal_code", label: "W11 1PN"}]
```

but sometimes like so:

```
var res = [{data: "route", label: "Ladbroke Grove"},
           {data: "postal_town", label: "London"},
           {data: "administrative_area_level_1", label: "England"},
           {data: "postal_code", label: "W11 1PN"}]
```

so it missed the "street_number".

Now how can i check if that specific data-value exists, regardless of what label-value is? And i don't wanna check on `res.length` either, since the length of it is really different.

Comment: Rearrange your response into something you can use. Example: `const data = res.reduce((a,c) => {a[c.label] = c.data; return a;}, {})` Now you can check if `data.street_number` exists.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's really what i need! but it's the other way around, `a[c.data] = c.label`. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, pfft, you're right. I misread it, glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the dataset and check for the specific value you need.

```js
var hasStreetNumber = res.find((x) => x.data === 'street_number') !== undefined;
```

Is one of many ways you can check if the value you're looking for exists in the list.

Answer (score -1):

This is an array of JS objects. A simple option would be to iterate through the array and check for the presence of a certain String in each Objects' data value. The following would iterate through an array and return true if a data value in the array matches the input:

```
    function checkDataValue(array, dataValue) {
      let contains = false;
      for (i = 0; i <  array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]['data'] === dataValue) {
          contains = true;
        }
      }
    return contains;
    }
```